# Connecting the fullcalendar by Adam Shaw with a mysql database

Tags: ajax, mysqli, fullcalendar

I'm trying to return some database events with ajax in fullcalendar like this:

JavaScript

```
$(function() {      
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-02-27',
        editable: true,
        events: 'http://localhost/fullcalendar/connect.php'
    });  
});
```

connect.php:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fullcalendar");
$sql="SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC";
$query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $arr[]=array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'start' => $row['start'],
        'end '=> $row['end'],
        'url' => $row['url']
    );
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

It should work, since I've test it like Adam explained here [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wojakuduja/1/edit?html,js,output) ,and it work but with a js file and the json was directly wrote like this:

```
[{"title":"Meeting","start":"2015-02-27","end ":"2015-02-28"},{"title":"Meeting","start":"2015-02-28","end ":"2015-02-29"}]
```

Somehow the events param doesn't like how I wrote the code from connect.php, because it doesn't output anything and I dont know why....

Comment: Look in the developer console of your browser. What does the response to your AJAX call (to connect.php) look like?

Comment: @JAAulde , this:  GET http://localhost/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That is not the response to the AJAX call to connect.php. Find that AJAX call in the network panel (or equiv for what ever browser you're using) and determine if the connecting is being made and what data is being sent back.

Comment: @JAAulde the response is good,i receive what i need to,but still it doesn't output in browser...and that is the only error i get..

Comment: Add an `eventDataTransform` callback and put a `console.log(eventData)` in it. This will tell you what data Fullcalendar is seeing. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/